# Trying to update table: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a UPDATE function to pull the values from a form, and update MySQL table on submit, but getting the above error. I've successfully used the exact same method for adding an entry and can't see the issue!

Every Time I submit I get:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp64\www\app\updatediary.php on line 32

Line 32 is:

':Appt_Type_ID' => $_POST['Appt_Type_ID']

My Form:

```
    <form class="editapptform" action="updatediary.php" method="post">
<main>

<div class="search-box">

<label for="">Patient</label>

<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result11)):;?>
<input class="ApptID hidden" name="ApptID" value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="ptIDin" autocomplete="off"  disabled="true" value="<?php echo $row1[2];?>"/>
        <?php endwhile;?>

</div>
        <div class="input__icon">
<input type="text" name="PersonID" id="personID">
</div>
        <div class="input__icon">
        <label for="">Appointment Type:</label>

<select class="apptdropdown" name="Appt_Type_ID">


<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>

            <?php endwhile;?>    

        </select>


</div>
        <div class="input__icon hidden">

<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="title">
</div>
<div class="input__icon">
<label for="">Start Date</label>
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result12)):;?>
<input id="startdateinput" type="date" name="startdate" value="<?php echo $row1[3];?>">


</div>
        <div class="input__icon">
        <label for="">End Date</label>
<input id="enddateinput" type="date" name="enddate" value="<?php echo $row1[4];?>">

</div>
        <div class="input__icon">
        <label for="">Start</label>
<input id="starttimeinput" type="time" name="starttime" value="<?php echo $row1[5];?>">

</div>
        <div class="input__icon">
        <label for="">End</label>
<input id="endtimeinput" type="time" name="endtime" value="<?php echo $row1[6];?>">

</div>
<div class="input__icon">
        <label for="">Appointment Colour</label>
        <input name="background_color" type="color" value="<?php echo $row1[9];?>">
        </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
        <div class="input__icon">
        <label for="">Status</label>

<select class="apptstat" name="appt_status_ID">

           <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)):;?>

            <option  value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>

            <?php endwhile;?>

        </select>

        </div>

<div class="input__icon">
<label for="">Booking Notes</label>
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result13)):;?>
<textarea name="apptnotes" rows="2"><?php echo $row1[10];?></textarea>

</div>

</main>
<footer>
<input type="submit" value="Book Appointment" class="button add"> <button class="cancel button" id="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="return false">Cancel</button>
</footer>

<script>
$("select.apptdropdown").val("<?php echo $row1[11];?>");
$("select.apptstat").val("<?php echo $row1[12];?>");
</script>
 <?php endwhile;?>

</form>
```

My PHP submit file:

```
   <?php

//insert.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST["ApptID"]))
{
 $query = "
UPDATE events SET 
Appt_Type_ID = ':Appt_Type_ID', 
start_event = 'CONCAT(:start_event_date,' ',:start_event_time)', 
end_event = 'CONCAT(:end_event_date,' ',:end_event_time)',
background_color = ':background_color',
appt_status_ID = ':appt_status_ID',
title = ':title',
notes = ':apptnotes'
WHERE id = :ID
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':ID'  => $_POST['ApptID'],
   ':start_event_time' => $_POST['starttime'],
   ':end_event_time' => $_POST['endtime'], 
     ':start_event_date' => $_POST['startdate'], 
   ':end_event_date' => $_POST['enddate'],
    ':apptnotes' => $_POST['apptnotes'], 
      ':appt_status_ID' => $_POST['appt_status_ID'],  
        ':background_color' => $_POST['background_color'], 
        ':title' => $_POST['title'],
    ':Appt_Type_ID' => $_POST['Appt_Type_ID'] 




  )
 );
}

//header("refresh:1; url=index.php");
?>
```

Comment: The reason Shadow marked it as duplicate is because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14795485/1839439) is the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is single quotes in the SQL text. Single quotes delimit string literals.

```
UPDATE events SET 
Appt_Type_ID = ':Appt_Type_ID', 
               ^             ^
start_event = 'CONCAT(:start_event_date,' ',:start_event_time)', 
              ^                         ^ ^                   ^
```

Note that this token `':Appt_Type_ID'` is a string literal. In this context, the semicolon character has no special meaning, it's just a character in a string.

Same with this token `'CONCAT(:start_event_date,'` , that's just a string literal. MySQL isn't going to see a call to the CONCAT function.

That same issue is repeated throughout the statement.

---

I suspect what you are after is something like this:

```
UPDATE events 
   SET appt_type_id     = :Appt_Type_ID
     , start_event      = CONCAT(:start_event_date,' ',:start_event_time)
     , end_event        = CONCAT(:end_event_date,' ',:end_event_time)
     , background_color = :background_color
     , appt_status_ID   = :appt_status_ID
     , title            = :title
     , notes            = :apptnotes
 WHERE id = :ID
```

(Note that the bind placeholders (starting with the colon character) are not enclosed in single quotes, they are bare tokens.)

Comment: that's fantastic! did exactly the trick. many thanks